# Как сделать прозрачный фон в шейдере?

Tags: three.js, webgl, шейдеры, glsl

Всем доброго времени суток, я только начинаю свой путь в webGL, threejs, fragment/vertex shader'ах и столкнулся с такой проблемой: 
Есть картинка с прозрачным фоном, но когда я передаю её в шейдер, то фон черного цвета. Как я могу это победить?

мой js:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {TimelineMax} from 'gsap';
let OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE);


let container;
let camera, scene, renderer;
let uniforms;
let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

init();
animate();

function init() {
    container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

    camera = new THREE.Camera();
    camera.position.z = 1;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    let geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2, 2 );

    uniforms = {
        u_time: { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
        u_resolution: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
        u_mouse: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
        texture: {value: loader.load("/assets/img/1.png")},
        alpha: {value: 0.0625}
    };

    let material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
        uniforms: uniforms,
        vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
        transparent: true
    } );

    let mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );



    onWindowResize();
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    document.onmousemove = function(e){
        uniforms.u_mouse.value.x = e.pageX
        uniforms.u_mouse.value.y = e.pageY
    }
}

function onWindowResize( event ) {
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    uniforms.u_resolution.value.x = renderer.domElement.width;
    uniforms.u_resolution.value.y = renderer.domElement.height;
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
}

function render() {
    uniforms.u_time.value += 0.05;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

vertexShader:

```
varying vec2 vUv;
    void main() {
        vUv = (position.xy+1.0)*0.5;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
```

fragmentShader:

```
varying vec2 vUv;
    uniform vec2 u_resolution;
    uniform vec2 u_mouse;
    uniform float u_time;
    uniform sampler2D texture;
    uniform sampler2D map;
    uniform float alpha;

    void main() {
        vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;

        vec4 texture = texture2D(texture, vUv);
//        gl_FragColor=vec4(st.x,st.y,0.0,1.0);
        if ( texture.a < .1 ) discard;
        gl_FragColor = vec4(texture.rgb, 1.);
    }
```

[Моя картинка с прозрачным фоном](https://yadi.sk/i/rQw77DLC8SxIWA)

Я попробовал запустить [пример](https://codepen.io/krayswork/pen/JgOqYb?editors=0010) на codepen, но то ли текстура не грузится, то ли что-то ещё...

Comment: по поводу текстуры - во всем виноват cors, если выкладывать картинки на imgur, а запрашивать из сниппета на stackoverflow, то он разрешен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема с инициализацией рендерера, необходимо указать `{ alpha: true }` и  будет прозрачность

```js
let container,camera, scene, renderer,uniforms;
let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

init();
animate();

function init() {
    container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
    camera = new THREE.Camera();
    camera.position.z = 1;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    let geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2, 2 );

    uniforms = {
        u_time: { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
        u_resolution: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
        u_mouse: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
        texture: {value: loader.load("https://i.imgur.com/YkXmKTC.png")},
        alpha: {value: 0.0625}
    };

    let material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
        uniforms: uniforms,
        vertexShader: `
          varying vec2 vUv;
          void main() {
              vUv = (position.xy+1.0)*0.5;
              gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
          }
        `,
        fragmentShader: `
          varying vec2 vUv;
          uniform vec2 u_resolution;
          uniform vec2 u_mouse;
          uniform float u_time;
          uniform sampler2D texture;
          uniform sampler2D map;
          uniform float alpha;

          void main() {
              vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
              vec4 texture = texture2D(texture, vUv);
              if ( texture.a < .2 ) discard;
              gl_FragColor = vec4(texture.rgba);
          }
        `,
        transparent: true
    } );

    let mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    onWindowResize();
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    document.onmousemove = function(e){
        uniforms.u_mouse.value.x = e.pageX
        uniforms.u_mouse.value.y = e.pageY
    }
}

function onWindowResize( event ) {
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    uniforms.u_resolution.value.x = renderer.domElement.width;
    uniforms.u_resolution.value.y = renderer.domElement.height;
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
}

function render() {
    uniforms.u_time.value += 0.05;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0;overflow:hidden">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/104/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<div id=container></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Госпади, да ты чёртов гений!!! Я провел в поисках этого решения несколько дней, прежде чем отчаялся и задал здесь вопрос... Огроменное СПАСИБО!!

Comment: @AleksandrKrais нет проблем, обращайтесь